# Projecting $512\times 1$ vector to lower dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

Say I have a $512\times 1$ vector, is it possibly to project this vector to lower dimensions while still retaining some approximation of the data?

Not sure if this question make sense.

Basically I have some set of $512\times 1$ vectors, these vectors represent an embedding of sentences from a machine learning model. I would like to visualize these embedding in 3D space.

I have two ideas for this:

1.) Somehow reduce to $512\times 1$ vector to a $3\times 1$ presentation. I know Principle Component Analysis can do this for a $N\times M$ matrix, but can I do it on a $N\times 1$ vector.

2.) Create a visualization with variable axes. So kind of slicing the $512$ space up into many different $3$D slices.

Do either of these approaches make sense mathematically or are they nonsense?

Comment: Have you considered approaches like TSNE:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding .  I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your second idea

Comment: Looks like TSNE is used here http://projector.tensorflow.org/, and this is the kind of 3D space I was thinking of generating. So I will try that.

Comment: My second idea was to take 3 dimensions at random from the 512 vector, visualize that. 
Pick another 3 dimensions visualize that. And so on just seeing if any interesting patterns emerge in that. Kind of tedious though

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is something along the lines of the ["eigenfaces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) application of PCA.

I recommend you apply PCA to some set of "training data", which consists of $M$ column-vectors of length $N$. Let's say that $A$ is the training data matrix, and $\mu$ is the "average" matrix, i.e. $\mu = \frac 1{M} Aee^T$ where $e = (1,\dots,1)^T$.  Let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ denote the first $3$ principal components, i.e. the first $3$ columns of $U$ in the SVD $(M - \mu) = U\Sigma V^T$.

For your new measurement, a single $N \times 1$ vector $v$, the $3 \times 1$ vector $(u_1^T v, u_2^Tv,u_3^Tv)$ can be thought of as your projection that (in some sense) retains information about the data; moreso than any other projection onto $\Bbb R^3$.

For more information on that, I would recommend looking at Bishop's *"Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning"*.

Comment: Right so im just using a pertained model right now, with no access to training data https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11175.pdf. 

My goal was to use to to map sentence similarity across 3 dimensions, and see if any interesting patterns emerge if I visualize them in 3D space.

Comment: actually looks like this tool from tensorflow does exactly where I was talking about http://projector.tensorflow.org/

Comment: What do you mean by a "pertained model"? And isn't the link doing what I describe here?

Comment: I mean I am not training a model myself, I am using the one described in the paper above. That is what gives me the 512x1 sentence embeddings. 

And yes I think it is. I found that link after asking the question.

Comment: @RobertLemiesz Ok so your real question, then, is how can you use a given model to project a $512 \times 1$ vector to $3$ dimensions. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes exactly. However given that I cant control the model itself; I figured I would get the 512x1 vector from the model, then some how project that to 3x1.

Comment: @RobertLemiesz But how are you supposed to decide what the important "components" of the vector are if you use absolutely no information about the data or the model?

Comment: I guess you are right I dont really know which components are important. So i guess the more interesting thing to compute would be: Given I have 512 x N vectors (N is the number of sentences I am comparing), figure out which of those 512 dimensions have the most tightly packed clusters. Rather than arbritrarly projecting 512 -> 3.